# Tag for military applications of OR

Tags: discussion, tags

Since the field of Operations Research (OR) was (partly) spawned by WWII, I took the liberty of creating tag [military](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/military) for questions on military applications of OR. I assume there are no objections to the creation of this tag. If there are such objections, please do consider taking some time to share them.

---

<sub>**Update:** tag [military](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/military) has been removed — automatically, I assume.</sub>

Comment: That should be alright. In any case it is not expected that many of these questions will arise, and indeed only one has been asked so far.